# XSLT: Output Javascript in the element tag

Tags: javascript, xslt

With XSLT, how do I output the following

```
<div onclick="var e = document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="div_id"/>');
          if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
          else
          { 
            e.style.display = 'block';
            e.scrollIntoView();
          }" 
          style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;"
>Toggle</div>
```

**Note:** The code should reside in `onclick` attribute, I have access only to the body of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One way to do this is by using AVT ([Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates))**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <div style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;"
     onclick="var e = document.getElementById('{div_id}');
              if(e.style.display == 'block')
                e.style.display = 'none';
              else
              {{
                e.style.display = 'block';
                e.scrollIntoView();
              }}">Toggle</div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<div_id>3</div_id>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<div style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;" onclick="var e = document.getElementById('3');               if(e.style.display == 'block')                 e.style.display = 'none';               else               {                 e.style.display = 'block';                 e.scrollIntoView();               }">Toggle</div>
```

**Do note**: When specifying such AVT (attribute-value-template) one must double any `{` or `}` characters that must be generated.

**Another way is to use `xsl:attribute`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <div style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;">
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
     var e = document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="div_id"/>');
              if(e.style.display == 'block')
                e.style.display = 'none';
              else
              {
                e.style.display = 'block';
                e.scrollIntoView();
              }</xsl:attribute>Toggle</div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! AVT + doubling of the ``{`` and ``}`` was **exactly** the thing I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) e.g.

```
<div onclick="var e = document.getElementById('{div_id}'); ...">Toggle</div>
```

Comment: That's what I was writing just now, so here at least a link: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N1575.html